# TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined (Angular)

Tags: angular, undefined

I have a server which return me an object and on page everything works fine but in console I have this `TypeError`. I understand that it's 'cause `ngOnInit` has Observable\Promise\Async method, and not waiting for the response, but why my `async await` doesn't work?

Here's my code:

```
candidate: ICandidatesInfo;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCandidate();
}

async getCandidate() {
    await this.candidateInfoService
      .getById(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
      .toPromise().then((candidate) => {
        this.candidate = candidate;
      });
}
```

In `.html` I use `{{candidate.email}}` and I can see the result on page but in console still have error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined`

Here's my another version with `Observable`

In service:

```
getById(id: string): Observable<ICandidatesInfo> {
  return this.http.get<ICandidatesInfo>(`${this.url}/${id}`);
}
```

Function:

```
getCandidate() {
     this.candidateInfoService
      .getById(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
      .subscribe(candidate => this.candidate = candidate);
  }
```

Would be really grateful for any help!

Comment: `candidate` is `undefined` *until the request completes*, you need to deal with that. I wrote a blog post about approaches here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html.

Comment: `{{candidate?.email}}` would solve your console.log error. I would preferably use observables and async pipe in this scenario. Would make your life much easier.

Comment: please do not use async/await in Angular ! Neither do use Promises ! Use Observables !

Answer (score 0):

Try to refactor your code and use Angular's observable as :

In your service make your getById method as :

```
getById(id : string) : Observable
```

In your component class method should be like :

```
getCandidate() {
     this.candidateInfoService
      .getById(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
      .subscribe(candidate => this.candidate = candidate);
}
```

Coming to your question now,
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

This tells that your Candidate is undefined, so it cant get email. Try to refactor your code and check if it works !

Edit : {{candidate?.email}}
Add ? after candidate that will help you null check candidate's value

Comment: Actually it was my previous version of code but I got an Error and tried to rewrite it with `async await`, but still without any luck.. (I edit this question and add my old code with Observable)

Comment: @Anna is there any other place in your code where you are trying to access this email from candidate ?

Comment: Yes, but there I use component inside component and pass my `candidate` by `@Input`, so can use once `*ngIf` and this case is separate  simple page

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the variable `candidate` as an empty object at the beginning.

```
candidate: ICandidatesInfo = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using async/await you can use Observable.

```
candidate$: Observable<ICandidatesInfo>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCandidate();
}

public getCandidate() {
    this.candidate$ = this.candidateInfoService
      .getById(this.route.snapshot.params['id']); // No need to call subscribe here
}
```

And in your html:

```
<div *ngIf="candidate$ | async; let candidate">
    <p>{{candidate.email}}</p>
</div>
```

And if you mind about making an extra `<div>` tag, it can be change to:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="candidate$ | async; let candidate">
    ...
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a good way and I know about it. In other cases I usually use this `*ngIf` method in html, but in this one I have a table with  a lot of separate cells and I thought that putting  `*ngIf` to each of them wont be a good practice.  So I wanted to check it in function and only after finishing pass to `ngOnInit`